# Ubuntu 18.04: XPS 15 9570 freezes when using GPU

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, dell, xps

This problem has bothered me for a couple of months. I've tried a couple of ways online, the most positive one is to set both `nouveau.runpm` and `nouveau.modeset == 0`.

However, sometimes it runs smoothly, sometimes it freezes after 2-3 minutes. The only option I can do then is to reboot with Magic SysRQ keys. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the NVIDIA GPU because it only happens when I use NVIDIA mode with prime-select.

My work has something to do with the GPU very often so that's why I'm still bearing with it.

Does anyone have any permanent solutions for this?

Comment: With the proper Nvidia drivers installed you shouldn't need any additional boot parameters.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Could you give more details on proper install? Do you use XPS 15? I'm having driver v415.27.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I added ```ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa``` repository and installed via ```ubuntu-drivers autoinstall```

Comment: Well, that should install it correctly. Have you already tried without the boot parameters?

Comment: Yes and it failed so I started looking for some fixes, but nothing has worked perfectly so far.

Comment: If it fails then there's something wrong with the Nvidia drivers. Try purging and reinstalling.